# Invalid CSR, Invalid Certificate error for generating Apple Distribution Certificate

Tags: xcode, keychain, csr

I have been generating Distribution certificates on Apple developer portal from the last 4 years but this time I am facing an error while uploading **.certSigningRequest** file.

I have created it like the way I always created i.e. Keychain Access -> Request a certificate from a Certificate authority -> User Email address (Development App ID) -> Save to Disk -> Done

I have also updated my **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority** certificate but found no luck.

That would be great if I get any other solution.[image]

**Update**

I solved it by not leaving **Common Name field** while creating .certSigningRequest which was not the case before.

Comment: you can also post the update as an answer and accept it as corrected.

Comment: Done that. Cheers mate

Comment: I am glad you solved it chittay ;)

Comment: It's working now, previously it's don't have that restriction

Comment: I have similar problem when trying to create signing certificate by Xcode for non-paid developer account, and there is no way to overcome this

Answer (score 39):

I solved it by not leaving **Common Name** field while creating .certSigningRequest which was not the case before.

Comment: worked for me as well after trying after 3rd time first time it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

common name equals to the domain name of the server.
Did you typed it in with "." notation format?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).